# How to rewrite recursive SQL query to work with Ignite SQL queries

Tags: sql, subquery, h2, ignite

I am migrating a project from using hibernate/postgres to using Apache Ignite caches which are configured to use postgres as a persistent store.

I am having a problem with the following query which results in this error:

> javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to parse query. Column "S.TAGID" not found; SQL statement:

Code:

```
WITH RECURSIVE reportIdList AS 
(
    SELECT reportId, tagId, owner 
    FROM "MyReportPojoCache".MyReportPojo 
    WHERE id = ANY (SELECT id 
                    FROM "MyOtherReportPojoCache".MyOtherReportPojo 
                    WHERE owner IS NOT NULL 
                      AND isManage IS TRUE
                      AND type = 'tag-group')               
    UNION 
    SELECT m.reportId, m.tagId, m.owner 
    FROM "MyReportPojoCache".MyReportPojo m 
    INNER JOIN reportIdList s ON s.tagId = m.reportId 
                              AND s.owner IS NOT NULL 
                              AND s.owner != 'admin' 
                              AND s.owner = m.owner 
) 
SELECT qpIntId 
FROM "MyReportPojoCache".MyReportPojo 
WHERE (report_id, owner) IN (SELECT report_id, owner FROM reportIdList)
```

From reading it looks like the reason for this is explained in [this](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/distributed-joins) documentation, and is that Ignite cannot resolve the columns of reportIdList after the Inner Join.

Accordingly I tried the following modification but got the error below.

Is there any way to restructure this query so it can be understood by Ignite?

> Subquery is not a single column query; SQL statement:

```
WITH RECURSIVE reportIdList AS 
(
    SELECT reportId,tagId,owner 
    FROM "MyReportPojoCache".MyReportPojo 
    WHERE id = ANY (SELECT id FROM "MyOtherReportPojoCache".MyOtherReportPojo 
                    WHERE owner IS NOT NULL 
                      AND isManage IS TRUE 
                      AND type = 'tag-group')
    UNION 
    SELECT m.reportId, m.tagId, m.owner
    FROM "MyReportPojoCache".MyReportPojo m 
    INNER JOIN "MyReportPojoCache".MyReportPojo s ON s.tagId = m.reportId 
                                                  AND s.owner IS NOT NULL
                                                  AND s.owner != 'admin' 
                                                  AND s.owner = m.owner 
) 
SELECT qpIntId 
FROM "MyReportPojoCache".MyReportPojo 
WHERE (reportId, owner) IN (SELECT reportId, owner FROM reportIdList)
```

Update:
I tried the suggestion by @alamar and tried to run the query remotely as a local query but still got the same results.
After Further [reading](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#recursive_queries) I think the issue is with H2 its support for recursive queries and not Ignite.

It looks like as far as I can understand ( I am not a sql expert) I have at least two problems:

1. Recursive queries need to be of the type UNION ALL (seems like a simple fix)
2. Parameters are only supported within the last SELECT statement (which is why it cannot resolve s.tagId)

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, Ignite does not support recursive CTE.
You may still try running it as a local query by setting `local=true` in your connection/query settings.

Comment: Tried running it remotely as a local query by using .setLocal(true) method but it still results in the same error.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I guess it is just not supported now.